# Get value in enter keypress event in angular material

Tags: angular, events, angular-material, mat

Trying to create an input with a clear button following the example from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/), [link to the example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/epdlypdaajg?file=app%2Finput-clearable-example.ts), what I want is to get the input value on a keypress enter  event.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keydown.enter)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Search" 
   name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
  <button mat-icon-button matSuffix aria-label="Clear" (click)="clearSearch()">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
  applyFilter(event: any) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(event)); 
  }
```

Results of the console when printing the event content:

```
{"isTrusted":true}
```

Comment: Try with `applyFilter($event.target.value)` ?

Comment: And since you use forms, consider using `applyFilter(searchValue)`

Comment: @trichetriche I think not `$event.target.value`, it is `event.target.value`

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT output variables are always called `$event` in Angular. Same goes for `(click), (input), (change) ...`

Comment: @trichetriche oh sorry, my mistake, I want to say that in component, we can access like `event.target.value`

Comment: @trichetriche @Javascript Lover - SKT I am getting no value, trying both  `$event.target.value` in html or `event.target.value` in ts

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue, because [on this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twpffw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) it works like a charm.

Comment: @ketimaBU did you try stackblitz example provided by trichetriche

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Im not familiar with this specific scenario of the component from Material Design, But the suggestions in the comments are the traditional way to do it. 
There might be an interruption from the MD component with the event, so you can try to manually pass the value to the function. something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #txtVal (keydown.enter)="applyFilter(txtVal.value)" placeholder="Search" 
   name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
  <button mat-icon-button matSuffix aria-label="Clear" (click)="clearSearch()">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
applyFilter(val: string) {
 console.log(val); 
}
```

`#txtVal` is just a local variable in the input field, so we pass its value manually to the function.

Comment: works fine for me...!

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to get the value using **`event.target.value`** in your **`applyFilter()`** method.

```
applyFilter(event: any) {
  console.log(event.target.value); 
}
```

Link to [**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-stackoverflow-3zkwzv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fstackoverflow-solution%2Fstackoverflow-solution.component.ts).